# Ruby On Rails 4, dynamically create nested association inside a nested association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I have 3 models

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :person
  has_many :doctors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :doctors, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :doctors
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init, unless: :persisted?
  has_one :address, as: :person
  belongs_to :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :address

  def init
    self.address ||= build_address
  end
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true
end
```

I am using simple_form and cacoon to handle my UI. 
I had to ask Specialist initialize address on Model level, other wise address of specialist does not get initialized for cacoon.

in my controller, I initiate my Doctor and Address with

```
@patient.doctor.build
@patient.address ||= Address.new
```

However, I got an error message if every inputs were blank for specialist's address.

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: addresses.line_1: INSERT INTO "addresses" ("person_type", "person_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Does this mean it automatically generate address during save even though

> accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

was set?

Is there any way to solve this? or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you know which address is giving you the error? (e.g. the patient or the doctor). Because I suspect the `init` in `Doctor` might be responsible for this.

Comment: It was the doctor. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Do not overrule the `init` method ;) afaik the preferred way is to define the special method `after_init` but even that is very dangerous, because your code might overrule existing associations (as you notice now too). I would just initialise an empty address in the controller for the doctor as you do for patient too.

Comment: The thing is initialization using cacoon does not go through the controller... which means dynamically initialized doctors has no address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `init` method to initialise the address. Instead, you should use the `:wrap_object` option cocoon provides ([documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#wrap_object)).

For instance, in your case that would become something like

```
link_to_add_association 'add doctor', f, :doctors, wrap_object: Proc.new {|doctor| doctor.build_address; doctor }
```

Comment: Another question, if the form failed validation but address fields were all empty, address will disappear on view. How should I prevent that while allowing_destroy on success submit of empty address fields?